# Refresh button for web browser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need a refresh button(to refresh a web page) for my web browser app for windows phone 7. Can anyone help me for this? My web browser control named as **"browsers"** and refresh button named as Refresh_Click.
Thanks in advance for your hard work!

Comment: Have you attempted any code?  What have you tried?  What hasn't worked?

Comment: Sorry, Josh actually i made a silly mistake in my codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty easy, try:

```
private void Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    browsers.Navigate(browsers.Source.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Coder, i also used the same codes but i made a silly mistake.
But now i got the mistake with the help of your codes.

Comment: @Robaticus - Thanks, I did that. Now only i know about that.